# Why does the summer holiday go so quickly?

Tags: time

Take 6 weeks at school or work and it'll feel like an eternity, If your out with your mates or on holiday, time flies! Why do we feel like this considering everyday contains 24 hours.

Comment: Welcome at CogSci. I found some related questions for you that may point you in the right direction: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/13919/11318 , https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/129/11318 , https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/10116/11318 . Have you done some initial research yourself already? Could you share what you did find?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer to this question, [Why do some days feel fast and others feel slow?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/why-do-some-days-feel-fast-and-others-feel-slow?rq=1), think that is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question. It seems the current questions is a duplicate of that one. This, however, does not constitute as an answer since it is just a link, but is a comment instead. Still, a very valuable one. I've flagged it for the moderator to move it to the comments, so you don't have to delete it.

Comment: Welcome at CogSci by the way! glad to have you here :)